# How to create a cordova plugin for my android library?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have developed an android library using which one can send messages to other android devices. I have developed many demo apps for mobile and watch to demonstrate this using native android projects. Now I want to explore hybrid android development. I want to know how a native android code can access my android library and use the functionalities.

I have come across custom Cordova plugins. Is it possible for me to build a Cordova plugin for my android library? If yes, can I then use it in a hybrid project and access the functionalities? If not, what is the best way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your 2 important questions:

**1. Is it possible for me to build a Cordova plugin for my android library?**

Yes, it's possible to create a custom Cordova plugin for your library. That's how all the Cordova plugins are dependent on the base Android library.

**2. can I then use it in a hybrid project and access the functionalities?**

Yes, you can.

Some are the links that might be helpful to create a new custom Cordova plugin.

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/
- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/plugin-development/android/
- https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. I will go through them. Also I was looking for any android code and how it looks after making a cordova plugin for it. This could help me to speed up. Do you have any links for it?

Comment: Camera plugin for cordova : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera